# Meat and milk with removable orthodontics

Tags: halacha, technology, meat-and-milk, eating, teeth

Is a person required to have different removable orthodontics (e.g. retainer, active plate etc.) for consuming meat and dairy?

Comment: regarding braces the Shevet Hakehasi writes that since most people only eat foods from a kli sheni and it’s not hot enough to cause problems then its fine and braces will not be problematic. However, he writes that one should be careful not to eat from a kli rishon and one should be careful that anymeat stuck in the braces should be removed. See the Maharsham 1:197 which discusses the lomdus behind this)... maybe this would apply to ur case.

Comment: Aren't they removed for eating, anyway?